# What does the 「とって」 mean?

Tags: words, verbs, manga

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 東のはずれには年を**とって**働けなくなった人たちのために養老院をたてるっ

Comment: You know 年を[取]{と}る, to grow older, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

年をとる means to grow old, to age.

Next time [try a dictionary first](http://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%92%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8B).

Answer (score 0):

年をとって means gained years (grown old).
働けなくなった unable to move
人たちのために for such people

Comment: I think you misread 働く as 動く.